# When using the pre training model of gpt2，meanloss = loss.mean(), but this error occurs: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: python, mean, loss

During the training, I tried to find the average loss, but I made a mistake

```
        loss, logits, _ = model(data1, labels=target1)
        meanloss = loss.mean()
        total_loss += meanloss
        meanloss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

then,this is the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Answer (score 0):

That must be caused by your model. Can you show the model your defined?

Here is an example:

```
>>> import torch
>>> from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

>>> tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
>>> model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

>>> inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
>>> outputs = model(**inputs, labels=inputs["input_ids"])
>>> loss, logits = outputs[:2]
```

Comment: I try to use your code to get loss, then the problem is solved. Thank you.